# How to calculate number of days since start of year with DateTime while accounting for leap years?

Tags: php, datetime, intervals

I'm trying to use a `DateTime` object to calculate the current date from the number of days since Jan 1st. Leap years are very important here. Apparently, this does not account for leap years, however.

Here's my code:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('z Y', '59 2016');
echo $date->format('n/j/Y')."\n";
die();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out this is a reported PHP bug from 2012 that I JUST found while I was making this question:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62476

That's annoying.

Here is a workaround:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', '01/01/2016');
$date->add(date_interval_create_from_date_string('59 days'));
echo $date->format('m/d/Y')."\n";
```